# Why "whiptail" is consuming 100% of my cpu on fedora on EC2?

Tags: unix, cpu-usage

One of my cassandra cluster node shows following result when I do 'top'

```
PID   USER      PR  NI VIRT  RES   SHR S  **%CPU** %MEM  IME+    **COMMAND**  
13351 root      20   0 20776 1476  324 R  **100**  0.0   2646:32 **whiptail**
```

I have not started this "whiptail" (Dont even know what is it) and it is somehow started and consuming 100% of my CPU and making my node unreachable.

How can I get rid of this? If i kill it will it make system unstable or any harm?

Comment: `man whiptail` http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/manuals/man/whiptail.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Whiptail](http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/manuals/man/whiptail.html)** is often used to write interactive shell scripts. Also, there are several packages that use it -

> alsa-utils
>       signing-party
>       rcconf
>       module-assistan
>       modconf
>       gkdebconf
>       ubuntu-minimal
>       psfontmgr
>       pppoeconf
>       pppconfig
>       gdm
>       friendly-recovery
>       defoma
>       debian-goodies
>       debconf

Did you make any recent changes to the system? You can kill it using `kill -9 PID`. If some package is using it then it would kick back in which might help you identify the root cause.